# How to setSupportZoom in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I know that there is a way to support zoom in java: `webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true)`. But I've been searching for a while for this in Kotlin. And yes, I have tried using the converter [try.kotlinlang.org](http://try.kotlinlang.org) but It gives me the same piece of code. Does somebody know how to support zoom in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
var webView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview)
webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
```

**Update**

As per your comments you would want to do this as well:

```
webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true // enable pinch to zoom and zoom controls
webView.settings.displayZoomControls = false // hides the zoom controls so you can just pinch to zoom
```

Comment: Sorry pasted the wrong code. Please see updated answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Are you sure it's in Kotlin?

Comment: 100%. What exactly do you mean by "not working"

Comment: There is no errors when I use `webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)`. But when I try zooming in, in my app, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Amy thats very different then what your question suggests, how are you zooming using your fingers or do controls appear on the WebView to allow zoom?

Comment: Please see my updated answer @Amy I think you are missing the call to `webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true` those are then the controls you should use to zoom in and out

Comment: I'm zooming in using my fingers.

Comment: Awesome glad to help. Dont forget you can also do `webView.settings.displayZoomControls` if you dont want the zoom controls to show when zooming!